# Why isn't select (mongoose query) working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm attempting to grab a User's highscore post. To do this, I query the `Post` model, finding posts with their `user._id` as the `author` in the post.

This is working just fine.

However, I only want to grab the `_id` and the `voteCount` of the post. For some reason adding a `select` just throws up errors and says that it's an `unprocessable entity`

Here is the query:

```
  getHighscorePost(req, res, next) {
    const firebaseUID = req.params.uid;

    User.findOne({ firebaseUID })
      .select('_id')
      .then(user => {
          Post.find({ author: user._id })
            .select('_id, voteCount')
            .sort({ voteCount: -1 })
            .limit(1)
            .then(post => res.send(post[0]))
            .catch(next);
      })
      .catch(next);
  }
```

I've tried putting the `select` before/after each of the `limit` and `sort` options.

If I omit the `select` then the post console logs just fine like this;

```
{ _id: '589ddffeb4a1477fa04d632a',
  author: '589ddffeb4a1477fa04d6326',
  text: 'This is post two. It belongs to Matt too',
  createdAt: 2,
  expiresAt: 1000000000000000000,
  university: 'University of Aberdeen',
  voteCount: 3,
  uniOnly: false,
  __v: 0,
  categories: [ 'music' ],
  votes: [],
  commenters: [],
  comments: [],
  expired: false,
  commentCount: 0,
  id: '589ddffeb4a1477fa04d632a' }
```

With the `select` added, I get nothing in the body. The error comes back as:

```
{ error: 'Cannot read property \'length\' of undefined' }
```

What's happening here?

Thank you

Comment: A couple of comments: You only need the outer `.catch(next)`, it will catch errors from the inner promise as well. You should also return `Post.find`. Try adding `.exec()` to the query before `.then()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you don't need semicolon in your select. So instead of this:

`.select('_id, voteCount')`

your select should look like this:

`.select('_id voteCount')`

At least I would say so based on [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select).

Comment: I'm doing this but it just gives me the same error?

Answer (score 1):

The `_id` should be included by default. You can try:

```
.select('voteCount')
```

Comment: I'm doing this but it just gives me the same error?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
Post.find({ author: user._id }, {voteCount: 1})
```

you don't need put _id = 1 as it will be in the output by default, but in case if you don't want _id in your output, you should put _id=0.

Here is the complete code:

```
getHighscorePost(req, res, next) {
    const firebaseUID = req.params.uid;

    User.findOne({ firebaseUID })
      .select('_id')
      .then(user => {
          Post.find({ author: user._id }, {voteCount: 1})
            .sort({ voteCount: -1 })
            .limit(1)
            .then(post => res.send(post[0]))
            .catch(next);
      })
      .catch(next);
  }
```

Hopefully it should work just fine but anyhow, let me know if this works.

Comment: I'm doing this but it just gives me the same error?